# How to create an XSL to output a Fixed Position Text File?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

Please find below a sample of the XML file that I have as an input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DATA_DS>
<ARCHIVEACTIONID></ARCHIVEACTIONID>
<DELIVERYOPTIONID></DELIVERYOPTIONID>
<PAYROLLACTIONID></PAYROLLACTIONID>
<FLOWINSTANCENAME>pb21</FLOWINSTANCENAME>
<G_1>
    <PAYROLL_ACTION_ID>665</PAYROLL_ACTION_ID>
    <G_2>
        <FILE_FRAGMENT>
            <Person_Benefit_Extract_Custom>
                <REP_CATEGORY_NAME>Person Benefit Extract Custom</REP_CATEGORY_NAME>
                <parameters>
                    <request_id>300000163751</request_id>
                    <FLOW_NAME>pbtestrun</FLOW_NAME>
                    <legislative_data_group_id/>
                    <effective_date>2018-04-07</effective_date>
                    <start_date/>
                    <report_category_id>300000163719</report_category_id>
                    <action_parameter_group_id/>
                </parameters>
                <Benefit_Child_Data_Group>
                    <OBJECT_ACTION_ID>1074</OBJECT_ACTION_ID>
                    <Person_Benefit_Traversal_Record>
                        <Benefit_Child_Data_Group>
                            <Benefit_1_Detail_Record>
                                <Emplyee_Person_Number>12345</Emplyee_Person_Number>
                                <Employee_First_Name>John</Employee_First_Name>
                                <Employee_Last_Name>Doe</Employee_Last_Name>
                                <Parent_Dependent_Bridge_Data_Group>
                                    <Benefit_1_2_Bridge_Traversal_Record>
                                        <Benefit_2_Child_Data_Group>
                                            <Benefit_2_Detail_Record>
                                                <Parent_Employee_Number>12345</Parent_Employee_Number>
                                                <Dependent_First_Name>Spouse First Name</Dependent_First_Name>
                                                <Dependent_Last_Name>Spouse Last Name</Dependent_Last_Name>
                                                <Dependent_Plan_Name>Medical Plan</Dependent_Plan_Name>
                                            </Benefit_2_Detail_Record>
                                        </Benefit_2_Child_Data_Group>
                                        <Benefit_2_Child_Data_Group>
                                            <Benefit_2_Detail_Record>
                                                <Parent_Employee_Number>12345</Parent_Employee_Number>
                                                <Dependent_First_Name>Child First Name</Dependent_First_Name>
                                                <Dependent_Last_Name>Child Last Name</Dependent_Last_Name>
                                                <Dependent_Plan_Name>Medical Plan</Dependent_Plan_Name>
                                            </Benefit_2_Detail_Record>
                                        </Benefit_2_Child_Data_Group>
                                        <Benefit_2_Child_Data_Group>
                                            <Benefit_2_Detail_Record>
                                                <Parent_Employee_Number>12345</Parent_Employee_Number>
                                                <Dependent_First_Name>Child2 First Name</Dependent_First_Name>
                                                <Dependent_Last_Name>Child2 Last Name</Dependent_Last_Name>
                                                <Dependent_Plan_Name>Medical Plan</Dependent_Plan_Name>
                                            </Benefit_2_Detail_Record>
                                        </Benefit_2_Child_Data_Group>                                           
                                    </Benefit_1_2_Bridge_Traversal_Record>
                                </Parent_Dependent_Bridge_Data_Group>
                            </Benefit_1_Detail_Record>
                        </Benefit_Child_Data_Group>
                    </Person_Benefit_Traversal_Record>
                </Benefit_Child_Data_Group>
            </Person_Benefit_Extract_Custom>
        </FILE_FRAGMENT>
    </G_2>
</G_1>
</DATA_DS>
```

The output should be a Fixed Position Text File displayed as follows (If a dependent exist, then print all dependents on the same row - If an employee exists, start printing from next row):

```
Field                            Start Position            Length
Emplyee_Person_Number            1                         10
Employee_First_Name              11                        15
Employee_Last_Name               16                        15
Parent_Employee_Number           NA                        10  
Dependent_First_Name             NA                        15
Dependent_Last_Name              NA                        15
Dependent_Plan_Name              NA                        15
```

Sample Output:

```
12345     John           Doe            12345     Spouse First NaSpouse Last NamMedical Plan   12345     Child First NamChild Last NameMedical Plan   12345     Child2 First NaChild2 Last NamMedical Plan
```

The second, third ... employees and respective dependents will print on new rows.

Comment: You've given us the requirements, but you haven't shown us what you've tried or where you're having problems. There's no actual question. It seems more like a ["Do you haz teh codez?"](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/13231) request.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a two-phase transformation. First generate a table using generic tags, say

```
<table>
  <head>
     ...
  </head>
  <row>
    <cell>..
  </row>...
</table>
```

Then convert this to the fixed-width ASCII rendition. You've tagged it both xslt 1.0 and xslt 2.0 so it's hard to know which you want. The simplest way to pad a string `$` to length `$n` is to have a variable `$spaces` containing a string of as many spaces as you will ever need, and then do `substring(concat($s, $spaces), 1, $n)`.

Comment: @techie-wiz - There's also an example of using a function to pad in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49262038/xslt-2-0-sorting-issue/49262428#49262428

Answer (score 0):

I think some push programming is in order.  This may work for you as long as the structure for your XML is static, even for empty values.

```
<xsl:template match="node()">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Benefit_1_Detail_Record">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
  <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Emplyee_Person_Number">
  <xsl:value-of select="substring(concat(.,'          '), 1, 10)"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Employee_First_Name">
  <xsl:value-of select="substring(concat(., '               '), 1, 15)"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Employee_Last_Name">
  <xsl:value-of select="substring(concat(., '               '), 1, 15)"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Parent_Employee_Number">
  <xsl:value-of select="substring(concat(., '          '), 1, 10)"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Dependent_First_Name">
  <xsl:value-of select="substring(concat(., '               '), 1, 15)"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Dependent_Last_Name">
  <xsl:value-of select="substring(concat(., '               '), 1, 15)"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Dependent_Plan_Name">
  <xsl:value-of select="substring(concat(., '               '), 1, 15)"/>
</xsl:template>
```